# Install Windows 7 from an external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, external-hard-drive

How do you install Windows 7 from an external hard drive?

I don't have a DVD ROM drive, so I copied my Windows 7 DVD (which is bootable) onto an external hard drive from another PC. However after booting with the external hard drive nothing happens!

What should I do? My external hard drive is formatted as FAT32 - is this important?

I was following [these instructions](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/05/19/AR2009051902418.html).

Comment: is any body here?

Comment: What OS do you have on your "other computer"?

Comment: Try with NTFS on your external HDD.

Comment: @KovBal NTFS shouldn't be a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following [these](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd535816.aspx) instructions at Microsoft Technet. They are a bit old and intended for USB keys but should still apply.

When creating a bootable disk (of any sort), the computer reads from a portion of the disk that is not visible like standard files, thus just copying files doesn't work. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector) for more information.

Comment: i want to change the file system to ntfs / so does the upper instructions work?

Comment: You want to change which file system to NTFS?

Comment: that external drive

Comment: sorry / i did n't see previous comments

Comment: i am testing ...

Comment: I don't know if the instructions will work with NTFS. I am not sure why you want to use NTFS; either way (FAT or NTFS) will erase everything from the drive.